# Verbot 5 change skin using editor Unhandled exception has occured

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

Im having problem in my Verbot 5 which is a chatterbot program that helps you to change skin for verbot 5 player. But when I save it shows this error in .vsk for my editor:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 

    just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

    ************** Exception Text **************
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       at Conversive.Verbot5.SkinEditorPopup.saveSkinData()
       at Conversive.Verbot5.SkinEditorPopup.saveSkinFile(String stPath)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


    ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
    mscorlib
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Verbot5Editor
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.2
        Win32 Version: 5.0.1.2
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Joes%20Lie/AppData/Roaming/Verbot5/main/Verbot5Editor.exe
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Windows.Forms
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Drawing
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Verbot5Library
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 5.0.1.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Joes%20Lie/AppData/Roaming/Verbot5/main/Verbot5Library.DLL
    ----------------------------------------
    Verbot4GUILibrary
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.2
        Win32 Version: 5.0.1.2
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Joes%20Lie/AppData/Roaming/Verbot5/main/Verbot4GUILibrary.DLL
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Xml
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Configuration
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    ngrugzdz
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    jcerfl3j
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    cp6v_jkg
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    dn1uhptc
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    AxInterop.AgentObjects
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.0.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Joes%20Lie/AppData/Roaming/Verbot5/main/AxInterop.AgentObjects.DLL
    ----------------------------------------
    03qpzprh
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    fr9-he53
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    System.Data
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_64/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    _nt9hdhw
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    rxalmiee
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    fu4y76dt
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    athmx-yq
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    ack8rygz
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    3ttmkmwy
        Assembly Version: 5.0.1.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8793 (WinRelRS2.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ----------------------------------------
    Interop.SpeechLib
        Assembly Version: 5.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 5.0.0.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Joes%20Lie/AppData/Roaming/Verbot5/main/Interop.SpeechLib.DLL
    ----------------------------------------
    Accessibility
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.8784 (WinRel.050727-8700)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
    ----------------------------------------

    ************** JIT Debugging **************
    To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
    application or computer (machine.config) must have the
    jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
    The application must also be compiled with debugging
    enabled.

    For example:

    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

    When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
    will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
    rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

First of all Verbot is a software to create chat bot, It respond answer through text and read by text to speech, it uses C# and .Net framework program.

I have no idea on this any help? Any suggestion?
Anyway Verbot is no longer supported by the developer.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the program?  It is a null reference exception thrown at this method `Conversive.Verbot5.SkinEditorPopup.saveSkinData()`

Comment: No, I didn't have the source code for the program, I used only for assignment purposes, The developed did not supported it years ago, So might hard to fix the problem

Comment: Then the last resort would be reverse-engineering the program to get the source code, it is easy to do by using tools like `ILSpy`. After you have got the code of that method, maybe you can guess which null object it is complaining about, if you are lucky. If you have the debug version and the symbol (PDB file), you can debug the problem with Visual Studio, but I think that is not an option for you.

Comment: Yes, Since the application is no longer supported, I wont use the application after assignment, Thanks for the time anyway